# Laravel add parameters to the URL

Tags: php, laravel, url, query-string

In my Laravel app, I have a query string after each URL to let the user select multiple clients over multiple tabs in his/her browser I read that out in my controller to select the right client. So it could look something like this: https://url-to-my-website.com/module/page?client_id=1

Now you can have multiple languages per client so I want to make it so that the user has that in the URL as well. So the end result would look something like this: https://url-to-my-website.com/module/page?client_id=1&lang=en

I am using the same code as I do for the client but for some reason, it's not working. Both functions are put in separate middlewares which I can call on the routes that need them.
This is the one for Client which works perfectly:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $url    = url()->current();
    $needle = '?client_id=';

    if ($request->get('client_id', null) === null) {
        if (mb_stripos($url, $needle) === false) {
            $lastUrl = url()->previous();

            if (mb_stripos($lastUrl, $needle) !== false) {
                $parameter = mb_substr($lastUrl, mb_stripos($lastUrl, $needle));

                $parameter = explode('&', $parameter)[0];

                $request->merge(['client_id' => mb_substr($parameter, mb_strlen($needle))]);
            } elseif (access()->getCurrentClient()) {
                $request->merge(['client_id' => access()->getCurrentClient()->client_id]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

This is the one for Language which doesn't work:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $url    = url()->current();
    $needle = '&lang=';

    if ($request->get('lang', null) === null) {
        if (mb_stripos($url, $needle) === false) {
            $lastUrl = url()->previous();

            if (mb_stripos($lastUrl, $needle) !== false) {
                $parameter = mb_substr($lastUrl, mb_stripos($lastUrl, $needle));

                $parameter = explode('&', $parameter)[0];

                $request->merge(['lang' => mb_substr($parameter, mb_strlen($needle))]);
            } elseif (access()->getCurrentStoreView()) {
                $request->merge(['lang' => access()->getCurrentLanguage()->code]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Any pointers will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: what errors do you get from the one not working? do you get a value from $request->get('store_view_id', null), is the difference in the $needle value of ? and & something to consider

Comment: try this `if ($request->has('lang')) {
       $lang = $request->input('lang');
}`

Comment: why are you using too complex code to get `lang` and `client_id`? you can simply use above comments code..

Comment: @noid I am not getting any errors, I have logged the code at certain points to make sure it works and the values are correct but it won't display the parameter-value in the url. The difference could be something but the lang will always be second so naturally it will have the & symbol infron of it, not the ? symbol.

BilalAhmed I am using this complex code because I need to check if the parameter-value pair is present in the URL of the user's browser. I have tried input but that just adds it to the request object but I don't see the value in the URL.

Comment: maybe this would be a better component to use: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls#accessing-the-current-url or this should do it: https://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getQueryString

Comment: @noid Those both give me options to get the current URL with or without the query string yeah. But they give no help in actually adding a parameter-value pair to the URL. I did change my code to use url()->full() instead of url()->current(). Since current gives the url without querystring.

Comment: once you have the full url, with query string you can extract it using parse_str() on the query string part.